# Generic function for generating dynamic components

Tags: angular, typescript

i would like to write a function in my service handling generating dynamic components in to some viewchild reference ...

i tried like

```
public GenerateDynamicComponent(ComponentName: string,viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, data?: any) {   
 switch (ComponentName.toUpperCase()) {
 case 'DYNAMICFORMS':
   const componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(DynamicFormsComponent);
   const formref = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
   formref.instance.Data = data;
   return formref;
   break;

 default:
  return null;
 }
```

and it does work well but i dont want to use this switch and send this componentname via string

so it would need to be like

```
 public GenerateDynamicComponent<T>(viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,data?: any ) {
 const componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory<T>(typeof T);
 const formref = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
 formref.instance.Data = data;
 return formref;
 }
```

but off course this does not work because typeof T <> component type...
is it possible to do or it need to be as in 1st example ?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A generic function to create dynamic components may be defined as follows.

```
public createDynamicComponent<T>(component: Type<T>, viewRef: ViewContainerRef): ComponentRef<T> {
    const factory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory<T>(component);
    return viewRef.createComponent(factory);
  }
```

And to call the generic function...

```
  this.createDynamicComponent<DynamicComponent>(DynamicComponent, this.vc /* ViewContainerRef */);
```

See [Stackblitz example app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-jtrja?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

#### Note: Be sure to add dynamic components to `entryComponents` in the module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DynamicComponent } from './dynamic.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, DynamicComponent ],
  entryComponents: [DynamicComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### Full Component Context

```
import {
  AfterViewInit, Component, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef, Type, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef
} from '@angular/core'
import { DynamicComponent } from './dynamic.component'


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <h1>App component</h1>
  <div class="insert-dynamic-component">
    <ng-container #vc></ng-container>
  </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
  @ViewChild('vc', {read: ViewContainerRef, static: false}) vc: ViewContainerRef;

  public constructor(private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // setTimeout() to prevent error "Expression has changed after it was checked"
    // See: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/
    setTimeout(() => {
      const componentRef: ComponentRef<DynamicComponent> =
        this.createDynamicComponent<DynamicComponent>(DynamicComponent, this.vc);
      componentRef.instance.data = 'New data';
    });
  }

  public createDynamicComponent<T>(component: Type<T>, viewRef: ViewContainerRef): ComponentRef<T> {
    const factory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory<T>(component);
    return viewRef.createComponent(factory);
  }
}
```

### DynamicComponent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-component',
  template: `<h1>Dynamic Component!</h1>
  <p>Data: {{data}}</p>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class DynamicComponent  {
  public data: any
}
```

Comment: thanks ! that was what i wanted to do - i have this func in service fut place does not matter - wanted one for all ;) also i wanted to pass data:any as Input Data field of this dynamic component
so 
const formref = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
   formref.instance.Data = InData;
it works as expected but compiler throw   ERROR in src/app/core/services/GeneralHelper.service.ts(131,21): error TS2339: Property 'Data' does not exist on type 'T'.
it is not a problem for me but can we do something that will not throw this error?

Comment: @d00lar See updated example that adds data to `DynamicComponent`.

Comment: yes that i did also but was wondering if possible to send this data as third parameter to  createDynamicComponent<T> and assing it inside of this func?

Comment: @d00lar The reason you do not want to send `data` to the generic `createDynamicComponent<T>` function is because there is no way to know for all possible components of type `T`, whether or not they will contain a `data` property. It is better to call component-specific methods and properties directly on the component instance returned by `createDynamicComponent` as shown in the example above.